# Using project reference instead of nuget package while developing?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, project

we have a project A (csproj, netstandard2.0) that we would like to release as a nuget package.

We want to use this package in project B using <packageReference> (csproj, .net framework 4.7.2) to speed up builds on our build server. Because we won't need to build project A before build of project B.

To ease development however i would like to have a solution that includes both projects, so that i can edit the source of project A and (re-)compile so that project B makes use of project A's latest version (**without** the need to pack a new nupkg of project A (and publish it on our nuget package source server if possible)). (While still using nuget on our build server)

How can this be archieved?

I searched the web and stackoverflow but couldn't find a way how this is intended to work.

Thanks

Comment: If you can use a project reference, that suggests both projects are in the same repo. Doesn't your CI build ProjectA anyway? How does making it a package reference in ProjectB make it faster? Do you have complex CI rules that only build a subset of your repo?

Comment: Does it need to be in the same repo? Yes the CI builds ProjectA but only when changes are made! Thereby making the build of ProjectB faster, as ProjectA does not need to be built all the time. I planned to have a separate repo for ProjectA (that could be added as a sub-repo in ProjectB)

Comment: Microsoft is doing the same in the asp.net core repository: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/DataProtection/DataProtection/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.csproj#L24. But I too would like to know an answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

As @Zivkan says, this is a bit of an odd thing to do for a number of reasons, but if you want to try it, I think the following would work:

You could use a conditional statement in your project so that when built locally it uses a project reference, but when built on the build machine you specify a property in the command line to use a package reference instead.
e.g.

```
<Choose>
  <When Condition="'$(IsBuildServer)' == 'true'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="A" Version="*" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="relativepath\A.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

And then when building on the build server, just make sure to specify `-p:IsBuildServer=true` as a command line argument to msbuild / dotnet build.

The "*" in the package reference just means take the latest available stable package, but may not be exactly what you want depending on what exactly you want the build server to build.

Comment: @toebens Apologies, apparently Conditions with custom properties can't be used directly on Project/Package references or their containing items groups, I've updated the answer to use the Choose When structure instead.
Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: i had/have it working with my property definied in Directory.Build.props file and using msbuild on console. Unfortunately Visual studio 2017 caches but does not update the cache when the file changed

Comment: At least partly, I think this is a known visual studio bug:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/433497/visual-studio-directorybuildprops-caching.html
  
If I've understood you correctly, specifying the target as Clean;Build rather than just Build when running on the build server and using a command line property rather than directory.build.props should work (in conjunction with the answer above).

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is a bit old, but I am leaving this answer to help future peers.

Leverage the dotnet pack command, when using it you can add a direct reference to a csproj. The only thing you need to be sure of is to use the property `IsPackable` and not generate a package on the build process. After that, the pack command will change the direct reference to a package reference. For more information check the dotnet runtime repo on how it's used.

The documentation for the pack command can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack